# Publishing Project Templates and cli tools to Azure Devops

Tags: templates, .net-core, azure-devops

I was wondering if anyone has done this and could point me in the correct direction. I have a dotnet project template in an azure git repo. It builds and I can publish it to the artifacts. The project template is just an empty project that has the structure, nuget references and config that is required. I would like to use this template locally.

My nuget.config file contains the azure stream url but if I do a "dotnet new empty.db.proj -o Berniez" it doesn't find it. If someone could point me in the right direction I'd be most grateful....

Comment: May i know what's artifact you mentioned? feed artifact or pipeline artifact? If you already have the template in the azure repo, it appears you don't need the artifact actually, just `clone the repo` to local machine, then you have the repo content on local for the command `dotnet new empty.db.proj...`

Comment: A packed new get package empty.Db.0.1.0.nupkg. I was hoping there was a simple way to share this with the team without having to jump through hoops. dotnet new empty.db

Comment: Please share your pipeline definition so we can know what content you are published in the nuget feed package. In addition, what's the error of `dotnet new ...` command? cannot find nuget.config or stream url? If you already have the project template, you can [publish as pipeline artifact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/pipeline-artifacts?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml), then you can download it as zip format and share to others.  Maybe there's some confusion in the statement.

Comment: So when I say "dotnet new install" I mean I expect it will inspect the nuget config file and download the template from azure instead. 

`- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1     displayName: "Publish Artifacts"     inputs:       PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'       ArtifactName: 'core_tools_bin'       publishLocation: 'Container'`

Comment: After you pack the template as `nupkg` file, you can use the `PublishBuildArtifacts@1` task to publish the nupkg file as the pipeline artifact, so you can download it to local machine. You need to install the package `dotnet new install <PATH_TO_NUPKG_FILE>`, then you can create a project using a custom template via command `dotnet new <TEMPLATE>`. Please check the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/custom-templates) for the process details.